# Mysql table rows deleted automatically

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have developed a website and its is currently running online, and the table are already filled with data by the user. Time and again few table rows are completely deleted first I thought someone had the password and deleted them and kept the database log for that purpose but also then the data are being deleted continuously and there is no any delete query. Please help I am in a great problem.

Comment: It would help a lot if you add the code where you are writing to the db. I find difficult to help with the information you are giving.

Comment: First, you have to taken your DB backup and change your `MySql` username and password.

Comment: Thanks J. PIchardo for your concern, the problem here is I have not written any of the delete query.

Comment: @nwemember I think you want to check. if you are find `DELETE` query in your project.

Comment: i will change the passwords and username of the database for the time being

Comment: Maybe there is some UPDATE queries which incorrectly change your data into empty rows or replace with new information instead.

Comment: How can we know your error? We can see nothing to help you debug.